# Columns/Images height are greater than what I want(Outlook 2007)

Tags: html, css, outlook, newsletter, campaign-monitor

I am trying to make a custom html newsletter for campaign monitor. Table width is 600px. I have 3 columns of images with text. Each column has a 200px width and 192px height. But when I see it in outlook 2007, I found those columns/images height are greater than 192px. I want the columns/images height to be 192px. How to solve this?

Note: Please don't run your head on classes. I have used the classes in media queries and I have no problem with it. The problem I am facing in outlook 2007(tested in outlook 2007). I need working code from you.

```html
<table width="600" class="hp" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td width="200" height="192" class="mob-column" background="https://i.imgur.com/sNVCXJg.jpg" align="left" style="width:200px; height:192px; background-image:url('https://i.imgur.com/sNVCXJg.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center center;" bgcolor="#000080">
         <!--[if mso]>
         <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:150pt; height:144pt;">
            <v:fill type="frame" src="https://i.imgur.com/sNVCXJg.jpg" color="#000080"/>
            <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true;" inset="0,0,0,0">
               <![endif]-->
               <div>
                  <table width="100%" class="hp" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding:42px 20px 32px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:15.43px; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:23.145px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff;" class="fallback-text-r">
                           <font face="'Roboto', Arial">Chicken</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0px 20px 0px 20px; color:#cac8c6; font-family:'Montserrat', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:10.29px; line-height:15.435px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff;" class="fallback-text-m">
                           <font face="'Montserrat', Arial">From</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0px 20px 42px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:25.89px; line-height:38.835px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff;" class="fallback-text-r">
                           <font face="'Roboto', Arial">$10.99</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </div>
               <!--[if mso]>
            </v:textbox>
         </v:rect>
         <![endif]-->
      </td>
      <td width="200" height="192" class="mob-column" background="https://i.imgur.com/DAQXLs7.jpg" align="left" style="width:200px; height:192px; background-image:url('https://i.imgur.com/DAQXLs7.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center center;" bgcolor="#000080">
         <!--[if mso]>
         <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:150pt; height:144pt;">
            <v:fill type="frame" src="https://i.imgur.com/DAQXLs7.jpg" color="#000080"/>
            <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true;" inset="0,0,0,0">
               <![endif]-->
               <div>
                  <table width="100%" class="hp" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding:42px 20px 32px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:15.43px; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:23.145px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff;" class="fallback-text-r">
                           <font face="'Roboto', Arial">Fish</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0px 20px 0px 20px; color:#cac8c6; font-family:'Montserrat', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:10.29px; line-height:15.435px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff;" class="fallback-text-m">
                           <font face="'Montserrat', Arial">From</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0px 20px 42px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:25.89px; line-height:38.835px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff;" class="fallback-text-r">
                           <font face="'Roboto', Arial">$10.99</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </div>
               <!--[if mso]>
            </v:textbox>
         </v:rect>
         <![endif]-->
      </td>
      <td width="200" height="192" class="mob-column" background="https://i.imgur.com/s9isrA4.jpg" align="left" style="width:200px; height:192px; background-image:url('https://i.imgur.com/s9isrA4.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center center;" bgcolor="#000080">
         <!--[if mso]>
         <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:150pt; height:144pt;">
            <v:fill type="frame" src="https://i.imgur.com/s9isrA4.jpg" color="#000080"/>
            <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true;" inset="0,0,0,0">
               <![endif]-->
               <div>
                  <table width="100%" class="hp" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding:42px 20px 32px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:15.43px; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:23.145px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff;" class="fallback-text-r">
                           <font face="'Roboto', Arial">Noddles</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0px 20px 0px 20px; color:#cac8c6; font-family:'Montserrat', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:10.29px; line-height:15.435px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff;" class="fallback-text-m">
                           <font face="'Montserrat', Arial">From</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0px 20px 42px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:25.89px; line-height:38.835px; text-align:center; color:#ffffff;" class="fallback-text-r">
                           <font face="'Roboto', Arial">$10.99</font>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </div>
               <!--[if mso]>
            </v:textbox>
         </v:rect>
         <![endif]-->
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Screenshot of outlook 2007

[image: Outlook 2007]

Screenshot of what I want

[image: I want]

Comment: I assure you, **no-one is using Outlook 2007** anymore. Why are you targeting it?

Comment: @Dai, For clients, if they want the newsletter looks okay in outlook.

Comment: Yes, but that's Outlook 2010, Outlook 2013, Outlook 2016, and Outlook 2019 - not Outlook 2007.

Comment: @Dai, Height is greater than 192px also in windows 10 mail, may be in other outlook versions also. Can you help me with working code?

Comment: I can - but not for free :)